# PHP connection to MongoDB not working and responding "trying to get property of non value"

Tags: php, linux, mongodb, apache, amazon-ec2

I have been trying to connect to my MongoDB atlas cluster using PHP version 7 on an AWS EC2 linux instance running apache2 to insert and update values in that database/collection.

I have installed the MongoDB driver version 4 and the MongoDB PHP library  1.5.5, set my IP whitelist to 0.0.0.0 on the MongoDB cluster as well as the AWS instance. I have also been reading almost every post on stackoverflow that has to do with other people's issues of connecting MongoDB with PHP in an ec2 instance and have tried a-lot of the recommendations in those with no success. Im GUESSING it has to do with where things might be installed, but I do not know why I can't connect :/

I used Composer to autoload libraries and the MongoDB.so file is in the correct place, and I can start the service in command line.

my doc root is set to /var/www/IOT/public where my code is, and have been trying to save all of the configuration files to /usr/lib64 or /etc/bin

My cluster is IOT, database is JT and collection is IOT

```
require_once '/var/www/html/vendor/autoload.php';

$connection = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager('mongodb+srv://${user}:${pwd}@iot-sjtus.mongodb.net/JT?retryWrites=true&w=majority');


   $db = $connection->JT;

   $collection = $db->IOT;


   $document = array(
      "title" => "MongoDB",
      "description" => "database",
      "likes" => 100,
      "url" => "http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mongodb/",
      "by" => "tutorials point"
   );

   $collection->insert($document);
   echo "Document inserted successfully";


I expected my collection to be updated with the $document but I get the errors

    Notice: Undefined property: MongoDB\Driver\Manager::$JT in /var/www/IOT/public/test.php on line 26

    Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/IOT/public/test.php on line 28

    Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function insert() on null in /var/www/IOT/public/test.php:39 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /var/www/IOT/public/test.php on line 39
```

[PHPinfo(); output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/92TQ2.jpg)

[PHPinfo(); php version output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bc6FE.jpg)

[PHPinfo(); mongodb version output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ATkx.png)

Comment: Please, check ["How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and ["How to ask"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You will get better results by following the tips on those articles.

Comment: All of the code errors seem to suggest that the connection was not successfully made. Are you able to connect to the MongoDB directly from the command line? Once you can connect to MongoDB from the same server outside of PHP you can start to focus on just PHP and package installation issues.

Comment: I can connect via the command line

Answer (score 0):

Seem your connections is wrong, I mean you are not connected with MongoDB

First try to catch the exception in order to know the root cause:

```
try {
   $connection = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager('mongodb+srv://${user}:${pwd}@iot-sjtus.mongodb.net/JT?retryWrites=true&w=majority');
   $db = $connection->JT;
   $collection = $db->IOT;
   var_dump($collection);
} catch(\Exception $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
```

Comment: It is showing that the variable $collection is NULL

Comment: Did you try to connect using MongoCompass (the ide for mongoDB), seems your collection does not exists